# Execute Java code block in org mode

Tags: java, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I can't seem to be able to evaluate Java code snippets in org mode. Here is what I have

```
#+BEGIN_SRC java
public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("hello world");
      }
  }
#+END_SRC
```

I get the following error: `can't compile a java block without a classname`. I can evalute python blocks just find though. The same java snippet works fine if I compile it with javac.

I have already enabled java in the emacs init file.

Comment: What happens if you make it public?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I am afraid that it still gives the same error. :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I should have done more googling, found the answer here:
http://ehneilsen.net/notebook/orgExamples/org-examples.html

```
#+HEADERS: :classname HelloWorld 
#+begin_src java  :results output :exports both
  public class HelloWorld {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Hello, World");
      }
  }
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Hello, World
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `:classname Test`, like this

```
#+BEGIN_SRC java :classname Test
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
#+END_SRC
```